# Show that $μ({x∈X:|f(t)|>t})≤ \biggl(\dfrac{\|f\|_p}{t}\biggr)^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, fubini-tonelli-theorems

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> If $f ∈ L^p(X, M,μ)$ then, show that for all t>0, $μ({x∈X:|f(t)|>t})≤ (\dfrac{\|f\|_p}{t})^p$. [Hint: Use Fubini’s theorem.]

I gave a try not using Fubini’s theorem but it is *indeed* wrong and having two variables $x,t$ in μ is confusing...

$$|f(t)|>t \implies \dfrac{|f(t)|}{t}>1 \implies \int_X \!\dfrac{|f(t)|}{t} dμ > \int_X\! 1\, dμ \implies \biggl(\dfrac{\|f(t)\|_p}{t} \biggr)^p > μ(x)\dots $$

A picture of the exercise :

[image]

Must $μ(X)$ be finite?

Comment: Should that instead say $\mu(x \in X: |f(\color{red}x)| > t)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_statement

Comment: @BenGrossmann, probably, but I don't know. One of the variable in $|f(.)|>.$ should be $t$ and the other $x$, I think.

Comment: Anybody: is the tag [fubini-tonelli-theorems] appropriate here? I guess the hint meaning is to use *layer cake*, not Fubini nor Tonelli...

Comment: @L.G. Different hint: try and write the Markov inequality for arbitrary measure spaces for the function $f^p$...

Comment: @OliverDiaz, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @OliverDiaz, https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Markov%27s_Inequality is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to prove it:

Note that $$0 \leq t^p \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{x \in X \;|\; |f(x)| \geq t \} } \leq |f|^p$$
It follows that
$$ t^p \cdot \mu{\{x \in X \;|\; |f(x)| \geq t \} } = \int t^p \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{x \in X \;|\; |f(x)| \geq t \} } d \mu \leq \int |f|^pd\mu= (\|f\|_p)^p  $$
So
$$ \mu{\{x \in X \;|\; |f(x)| \geq t \} } \leq \left (\frac{\|f\|_p}{t} \right)^p $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Fubini's theorem, although as I said in my comments, it may be an overkill.

$\int_X|f(x)|^p\,d\mu=\int_X \Big(\int^{|f(x)|}_0ps^{p-1}\,ds\Big)\,d\mu=\int^\infty_0\int_X\mathbb{1}_{\{t<|f(x)|\}}(x,s) p s^{p-1}\,ds=\int^\infty_0ps^{p-1}\mu(|f|>s)\,ds$

From that, for any $t>0$

$$\begin{align}
\int_X|f(x)|^p\,d\mu&=\int^\infty_0ps^{p-1}\mu(|f|>s)\,ds\geq\int^t_0ps^{p-1}\mu(|f|>s)\,ds\\
&\geq \mu(|f|>t)\int^t_0ps^{p-1}\,ds
\end{align}$$